# Caching Paperclip asset URLs to avoid network request when getting generated URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, fog

Is there an acceptable way to have Paperclip not make a network request each time you call `model.attachment.url()`?

I'd like to cache the URLs for faster load speeds / being able to load my development environment, without needing connected wifi, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the fog provider, it appears that you should be able use `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_host] = "http://myhost.com"` in your paperclip initializer to specify your host. This should reduce the look up calls.